# Why is "NoPT" indicated on this KYKM approach?

Tags: instrument-procedures

For LOC-DME approach (back course) at Yakima Air Terminal (KYKM), *NoPT* was mentioned at different locations on this 2008 plate:

[image]
<sup>Click for full plate. [Source](https://acukwik.com/extimages/FAA_Diagrams/00465LDBCB.PDF).</sup>

However there is no procedure turn at all. Why is NoPT mentioned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FAA_H_8083-15B Instrument Flying Handbook 2012

**Procedure turn.** A maneuver prescribed when it is necessary to reverse direction to establish an aircraft on the intermediate approach segment or  final approach course.

This particular approach doesn’t have a course reversal—the DME arc takes care of the course change from the YABLU IAF and the DATVE IAF. (Cut off on your map.) BABRE is an intermediate fix, and again needs no reversal.

So as you mentioned, there is no reason to state NoPT.

The version of the chart you used in your post is out of date. The current chart doesn’t mention NoPT, probably because there is no reason to. I’m guessing that mentioning it on your version is a mistake that they have since corrected or they are conforming to newer standards for chart making.

Comment: As you can see from the sides of the chart, your version of the chart is from 2008. The current version doesn’t show NoPT at any of the four IAFs. I also randomly looked at a dozen or so procedures in ForeFlight and the only time I can find NoPT is if there is a charted procedure turn. I have a set of Jepp charts from 2011 and same thing is done on theirs. I'm guessing that at one point there was a procedure turn for approaches coming from directly over the VOR and they forgot to remove the notation.

Comment: Did the altitude restriction change when the "noPT" was removed?

Comment: @radarbob Yes. The current altitude restrictions are 5800 from YABLU to BABRE (the bottom arc) and 7000 from BTVE to CADED dropping to 5800 to BABRE (the top arc). The arc is now 17 DME. Lots more waypoints and two more IAFs as well.